# Layout Manager not work properly when using in JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, layout-manager

I am creating a stand alone application for all types of screen sizes. For this I am using using JFrame, JPanel, Layout Managers, etc.

But I am making a mistake due to which I am not able to achieve it.

I took 3 JPanels and inside middle JPanel, I took various JLabels and JTextFields and a JButton.

Current Code:

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

import com.jindal.model.CustomerServiceModel;
import com.jindal.service.CustomerSearchService;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

/**
 *
 * @author Varun Jain
 */
public class PanelAddCustomer extends JPanel  implements ActionListener
{
    private javax.swing.JButton btnAdd;

    private javax.swing.JTextField fldName;
    private javax.swing.JTextField fldEmail;
    private javax.swing.JTextField fldFirmName;
    private javax.swing.JTextField fldCity;
    private javax.swing.JTextField fldAddress;
    private javax.swing.JTextField fldTinNo;
    private javax.swing.JTextField fldMobile;
    private javax.swing.JTextField fldPhone;
    private javax.swing.JTextField fldFaxNo;
    private javax.swing.JTextField fldTax;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblName;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblEmail;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblFirmName;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblCity;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblAddress;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblTinNo;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblMobile;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblPhone;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblFaxNo;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblTax;
    private javax.swing.JLabel lblAddCustomer;
    int customer_id;
    private  final Dimension PANEL_SIZE = new Dimension(93,37);
    public PanelAddCustomer()
    {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        lblAddCustomer = new com.jindal.ui.CustomLabel("Add Customer", new java.awt.Font("Calibri", 1, 36), java.awt.Color.orange, SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblName = new com.jindal.ui.CustomLabel("Name", new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18), new java.awt.Color(204, 51, 0));
        lblEmail = new com.jindal.ui.CustomLabel("Email", new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18), new java.awt.Color(204, 51, 0));
        lblFirmName = new com.jindal.ui.CustomLabel("Firm Name", new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18), new java.awt.Color(204, 51, 0));
        lblAddress = new com.jindal.ui.CustomLabel("Address", new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18), new java.awt.Color(204, 51, 0));
        lblCity = new com.jindal.ui.CustomLabel("City", new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18), new java.awt.Color(204, 51, 0));
        lblTinNo = new com.jindal.ui.CustomLabel("Tin No", new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18), new java.awt.Color(204, 51, 0));
        lblTax = new com.jindal.ui.CustomLabel("Tax", new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18), new java.awt.Color(204, 51, 0));
        lblMobile = new com.jindal.ui.CustomLabel("Mobile", new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18), new java.awt.Color(204, 51, 0));
        lblPhone = new com.jindal.ui.CustomLabel("Phone", new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18), new java.awt.Color(204, 51, 0));
        lblFaxNo = new com.jindal.ui.CustomLabel("Fax No", new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18), new java.awt.Color(204, 51, 0));

        /*fldName = new JTextField();
        fldEmail = new JTextField();
        fldFirmName = new JTextField();
        fldAddress = new JTextField();
        fldCity = new JTextField();
        fldTinNo = new JTextField();
        fldTax = new JTextField();
        fldMobile = new JTextField();
        fldPhone = new JTextField();
        fldFaxNo = new JTextField();*/

        btnAdd = new com.jindal.ui.CustomButton("Add", new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14), new java.awt.Color(204, 51, 0));
        JPanel jp = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2, 50, 10));
//        JPanel jp1 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
//        JPanel jp2 = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

//        jp.add(jp);
        jp.add(getLabelPanel(),BorderLayout.CENTER);
        jp.add(getFieldsPanel1());

        jp.add(getFieldsPanel2());
        jp.add(getFieldsPanel2());
        jp.add(getFieldsPanel1());
//        jp2.add(getFieldsPanel1());
//        jp2.add(getFieldsPanel2());

        add(getLabelPanel(),BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(jp,BorderLayout.NORTH);
//        add(jp1,BorderLayout.EAST);
//        add(jp2,BorderLayout.WEST);

//        add(getFieldsPanel1(),BorderLayout.SOUTH );
        //add(lblAddCustomer,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        /**
         * ******************** layout and background ******************
         */


        /**
         * ***************** Register listener *****************
         */
        btnAdd.addActionListener(this);
    }

    private Component getLabelPanel()
    {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(lblAddCustomer,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        return panel;
    }

    private Component getFieldsPanel1() {
      JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));

        panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        panel.add(new LabeledCustomerField("Name :  ", fldName),BorderLayout.NORTH);
        //panel.add(new LabeledCustomerField("Firm Name :  ", fldFirmName));
        /*panel.add(new LabeledField("City :  ", fldCity));
        panel.add(new LabeledField("Mobile :  ", fldMobile));*/
        return panel;
    }
    private Component getFieldsPanel2() {
      JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));

        panel.setBackground(Color.WHITE);

        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
//        panel.add(new LabeledCustomerField("Name :  ", fldName));
        panel.add(new LabeledCustomerField("Firm Name :  ", fldFirmName),BorderLayout.NORTH);
        /*panel.add(new LabeledField("City :  ", fldCity));
        panel.add(new LabeledField("Mobile :  ", fldMobile));*/
        return panel;


    }

        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                    return PANEL_SIZE;
                }

                public Dimension getMinimumSize() {
                    return PANEL_SIZE;
                }

                public Dimension getMaximumSize() {
                    return PANEL_SIZE;
                }
}

            class LabeledCustomerField extends JPanel {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
                JTextField textField;
                public LabeledCustomerField(String label, JTextField textField) {
                    super(new BorderLayout());
                    this.textField = textField;
                    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
                    add(getLabel(label), BorderLayout.WEST);
                    add(getEntry(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
                }

                private Component getLabel(String caption) {
                    JLabel label = new CustomLabel(caption, new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 0, 18), new java.awt.Color(204, 51, 0), SwingConstants.RIGHT);
                    //label.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(85, 25));
                    return label;
                }

                private Component getEntry() {
                    textField = new JTextField(50);
                    return textField;
                }
            }
```

Expected Output:

[image]

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: post your codes ..is that image your output ?what is the problem in this form ?

Comment: yeah! i want that image as Jframe output. The problem is, i am not able to add the JLabel and JtextField in JPanel by using layout managers.

Comment: @FastSnail - have you understood?

Comment: yes so that is expected output ..what do you mean by ` i am not able to add the JLabel and JtextField in JPanel by using layout managers` .post relevant codes and describe exactly your  problem.

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/) of your best attempt.  SO is not your personal coding service.

Comment: Hey Fast Snail/Andrew, check out the code.

Comment: `import com.jindal.model.CustomerServiceModel;` and the other non J2SE import should be removed..

Comment: @Varun: Please stop using code from the 70's, it is 2015, start using somethingy that Java is pressing programmers to use. Please do read, [BorderLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/border.html), for new names instead of `NORTH, SOUTH, EAST and WEST` and moreover, many `lookandfeel`s don't set `JPanel`'s opaque property to `true` by default, hence, one must explicitly use `JPanel.setOpaque ( true )`, before setting the background colour for the same. More info, on [Painting Problems](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/problems.html) :-)

Comment: @Varun: Why not instead of overriding `getXxXSize ()` methods, use a simple line like `frame.setResizable ( false );`? Won't this suffice?